# Loop through matrix field find first block of a type

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to loop through a matrix field that has a few different types of fields in it and different orders. I want to first the first field of a certain type and output only that. Here is what I have so far.

```
{% for block in entry.blogPostMainSection.all() %}

{% if block.type == "blogText" %}

    {% set articleText =  block.blogArticleText %}

        {% if articleText | length > 100 %}

            {% set articleTextTrim = block.blogArticleText|slice(0, 100) ~ '...' %}

            {{articleTextTrim | striptags}}

        {% else %}

            {{articleText | striptags}}

        {% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% set myFirstMatrixBlockWithType = entry.blogPostMainSection.type('blogText').one() %}

{{ myFirstMatrixBlockWithType.articleText }}
```

Keep in mind `entry.blogPostMainSection` is **not** an array of blocks but a `Query`